# Como colocar porcentagem em gráfico de barras?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Não estou conseguindo colocar porcentagem no gráfico de barras abaixo. Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me ajudar.

```
dado <- data.frame("Estado" =c("ALESP", "ALRS", "ALMG"),
               "teste" =c(9, 29,20))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dado, aes(x = Estado, y=teste, fill = Estado))+
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(1), stat = "identity")+ 
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  geom_text(aes(y = teste, label = teste), vjust = -0.2,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  xlab("Assembleias")  +
  ylab("CPIs que investigam o governo em %")
```

Comment: Você pode usar a função `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` do pacote `"scales"`

Answer (score 3):

```
dado <- data.frame("Estado" =c("ALESP", "ALRS", "ALMG"),
                   "teste" =c(0.09, 0.29, 0.20))
library("scales")
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dado, aes(x = Estado, y=teste, fill = Estado))+
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(1), stat = "identity")+ 
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  geom_text(aes(y = teste, label = scales::percent(teste)), vjust = -0.2,
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  xlab("Assembleias")  +
  ylab("CPIs que investigam o governo") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]